Mitre angle calculation
Im doing some mitre sawing where I cannot seem to get the correct angles for my cornice.
I have to saw it laying flat because there is no way I'll be able to support it standing up. Im unable to wrap my head around if this affects the cutting angles or not.
It will sit on a presumably 90 degree outside corner.
The cornice has a height of 75mm and projects 77mm, so I should be able to get the spring angle using arctan(height/projection), which comes out to 44.25 deg - correct?
Using the spring angle I've calculated the mitre angle using arctan(cos(spring)/sin(spring)) (45.87 deg), and the bevel using arcsin(cos(spring)) (45.88 deg).
But using these settings (well, 45 deg mitre/45 deg bevel since its what my saw is capable of) it just comes out grossly misaligned. I've also tried 22.5 deg mitre/45 deg bevel, 45 deg mitre/22.5 deg bevel.
What am I missing here? Is the clue in that Im sawing it flat?
All the best,
Chris

Perhaps better asked at https://diy.stackexchange.com/ Maybe with a sketch?
